# how to Limit the number of visible page links in pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently my pagination looks like this image below:

[image]

I don't want it to appear in this way. I just want it to have a few links. For example five page links and if I press next it moves to link number 6, 7, 8 and so on

```
<div class="shopping-pagination pull-right">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">13</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">15</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">16</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">17</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">18</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">19</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Given that your pagination is generated server side in PHP, why is this tagged with JS and jQuery?

Comment: sorry that was the typing error